# Solaris 11 list of supported USB wireless cards

Tags: solaris

I just installed Solaris 11.3 on my laptop. Unfortunately the internal card of this laptop (Broadcom BCM4312) is not supported by Solaris.

And so my question is: Is there a list of USB wireless cards with the manufacturer that are supported by Solaris?

I will go to the store and buy one and everything will be fine.

Thank you.

Comment: @Fox, I was actually looking for a list which will a "Manufacturer" and the "Model" of the card and also the interface it uses. Its going to be kind of hard to come to the store and ask for a card which has a chipset of such and such. I serously doubt they will help me. Also, I am not asking for a list of drivers here - rather for a list of cards supported by manufacturer and model.

Comment: @Fox, just curious - which store did you go to? and which country?

Comment: @Fox, yesterday I was at BestBuy and MicroCenter. Both were unable to find a card based on the chipset. Can you help a little further? Also just look here: https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-p-8042438.html#8042438.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle publishes a list of hardware that's officially supported on Solaris.  As of March 2017, the latest Solaris 11 Hardware Comparability List can be found at http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/hcl/data/s11ga/index.html

You may also find that OpenSolaris-derived (OpenIndiana, Nexenta) drivers from https://wiki.illumos.org work on Solaris 11.  To manually add drivers to Solaris, you need to follow the procedures at [**Installing, Updating, and Removing Drivers**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-3196/loading-85890.html).  Those directions are merely a *start*, however.  Full documentation is in [**Writing Device Drivers**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23824_01/html/819-3196/toc.html).  It's not hard to manually add a driver to Solaris, unless you run into problems.  For example:  in my experience even if your driver doesn't need data from a configuration file such as `/kernel/drv/xxx.conf`, your driver won't attach to your hardware without one.  The driver module will load, but nothing will work.  Knowing how Solaris manuals are written, that's probably documented somewhere like the bottom of p. 582 of the **Writing Device Drivers** manual as a parenthetical expression buried in a footnote, but I've never found it.